# Mongoose: Is it possible to set strict:false after defining the schema, like through a middleware or a plugin?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When you define a schema in Mongoose you have an option to set `{strict:false}`

Is there an option to have that set *after* you've defined the schema? Like through a [mongoose middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) or a [mongoose plugin](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html)?

I want to create a [plugin](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html) which will need to store some additional data into the database, which I wouldn't be able to unless the plugin user has either set `{strict:false}` or added the fields that I would want to store data in their schema themselves, both of which are unlikely. So I was wondering if there's a way for me to make that happen from my plugin code itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose is an ODM, and the `{strict: true}` option in this regard only applies to queries you run through Mongoose, it's not enforced in the mongoDB side, your documents remain schemaless.

But you don't have to use mongoose to make all of your queries, you can use the native mongoDB driver underneath in order to bypass all of that. Mongoose even gives you a shortcut to do so in the form of `Model.collection`. Here's an example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
}, {
    strict: true
});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    Person.collection.insert({
        name: 'Bill',
        extraProp: 'Hello World'
    }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(result);
        });
    console.log('Connected');
});
```

**Edit:**

You can disable `strict` for specific model paths. I think this is more what you're looking for.

```
PersonSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.set('extraProp', 'hello', {
        strict: false
    });
    next();
});
```

Comment: I want to clarify that I want to make [*mongoose* plugin](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html), so I definitely can't do a `mongoose.connect` or redefine the schema. That is all up to the plugin user.

Comment: The `mongoose.connect` I'm doing is only there for demonstration to make my example easy to execute. What makes you think you can't perform direct mongo queries from within a plugin?

Comment: But you can specify `{strict: false}` as the third parameter of `Model.set`. That's probably closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: I notice that your approach of setting `strict: false` works in middleware, and you have to define the value there... Is there a way to NOT define it there, and allow a regular query to insert any structure data for that item?

Comment: @Justin yes.. you can use the driver directly as in my original answer or pass the strict: false option to your Model.set call as in my comment above. I might be misunderstanding your question, if so this comment thread is the wrong place to discuss and you're probably better off posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI, what I ended up doing was creating a sub-schema, then disabling `strict` in there..

I was doing this for meta data, which is unstructured, so heres my example:

```js
module.exports = Mongoose => {
    const Schema = Mongoose.Schema

    const metaSchema = new Schema({},{ strict: false })

    const modelSchema = new Schema({
        title: Schema.Types.String,
        metaData: metaSchema
    })

    modelSchema.statics.createMeta = function( title, meta, cb ) {
        return new this({
            title: title,
            metaData: meta
        }).save()
    }

    return Mongoose.model( 'Foobar', modelSchema )
}
```

Then to use it:

```js
Foobar.createMeta( 'blah blah', {
    foo: 'AA',
    bar: 'BB'
} )
    .then( data =>  console.log( '# RESULT:', data ) )
    .catch( err => console.error( 'ERROR:',err ) )
```

Which seems to work fine :)